# How to index and retrieve ordered firebase nested data (3 level) using Python

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have firebase json data with below structure:

[Firebase Json Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUuLT.jpg)/i.stack.imgur.com/Rh45Q.jpg

Below is the index rule I have in Firebase:

```
"rules": {
    "Trip": {
            ".indexOn": ["tripLastUpdateTimestamp"]
       }
   }
```

And this is the Python code I used for retrieving the firebase data based
on the trip_LastUpdateTimestamp:

```
ref = db.reference('Trip')
snapshot = ref.orderbychild('tripLastUpdateTimestamp').start_at(1527647100).end_at(1527647200).get()
```

But the above code doesn't return any data.

Can you guys please help me to fix this problem? would be really helpful if you guys let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reference should be

```
ref = db.reference('Trip/Trial_345')
```

or, if you need to use a variable child id:

```
subRef = xyz //<-- set your variable value here
ref = db.reference('Trip/' + subRef)
```

Have a look at the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sort_data)

You rules shall also be adapted, with the same logic, i.e. at the level of the node that is the direct parent of the children nodes you want to order through `orderbychild()`

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Renaud Tarnec.

I can't hard code that, because "Trial_345" is not static it's a user entered value it can be anything.

Comment: I've updated the answer, showing how you can use a variable to declare you reference

Comment: Thanks Renaud, I'm quite new to Firebase. Could you please provide me an example as in how to set a variable value from firebase?

Comment: @RKiran The parameter to pass to db.reference() is just a string that should point to the corresponding database node. What do you exactly want to do? How do you query this database node. Can you modify your question to give more details on your business needs and also put the existing code into its context.

Comment: @RKiran Hello, did you have the opportunity to test this answer and try with passing a string to the `reference()` method?

Comment: Thanks a lot Renaud for helping me to solve this issue, As suggested by you I could extract the keys from Json and pass it to the reference() method. Now it returns the delta based on the date provided.

Comment: @RKiran Glad that I coud help! You may accept the answer, by clicking the grey checkmark on the left of the answer, see stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer. Thanks